# Warning about "xsd:date"

Tags: jena, turtle-rdf

I am using Jena to parse a "TTL" formatted file. I see the warning in the console

> Lexical form '1896-13-04' not valid for datatype http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date

I want to know why this warning happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the XML schema specification for [`xsd:date`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date):

> The ·lexical space· of date consists of finite-length sequences of characters of the form: '-'? yyyy '-' mm '-' dd zzzzzz? where the date and optional timezone are represented exactly the same way as they are for dateTime

i.e. dates must follow the International Convention of having year then month then day.

From the example given your data appears to have dates in the American convention which has year then day then month. Since 13 is not a valid month you receive a warning.

Your input data is not valid according to the specifications and therefore may not be processed correctly when you try to ask queries based upon that data e.g. Find items with dates before or after a specific date of interest. Dates for which you are not receiving a warning maybe interpreted incorrectly a day and month being interchanged.

You need to correct the data as otherwise this will cause you issues later. If the data is from a public data source you should let them know that they have a data quality issue, if the data is being created by yourself you need to correct your data generation so the dates following the specification.